# how to make ng-model value set by ui-select value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am currently using angular-ui/ui-select in my project. I am able to bind the value of the ui-select to an object without issue, however it is binding the entire `item` that is being iterated over.  I would like to only bind based on the `item.codeId` this would allow me to persist the correct data as well as display the correct value in the drop down when the page is loaded.

How can I setup ui-select to do this?

```
<ui-select ng-model="myObject.stateCode" id="stateCode">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select a state...">{{$select.selected.codeDescription}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="item in constants.states | filter: $select.search" value="{{$select.selected.codeId}}">
        <div ng-bind-html="item.codeDescription | highlight: $select.search"></div>
        <small ng-bind-html="item.codeId | highlight: $select.search"></small>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code is fine, but there was a bug that caused this when using a child array (constants.states).

I just fixed this issue at https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/pull/131, specifically [this commit](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/commit/8eddf0b88ca45daedb38f6d5ccdd4da250645936)

New version [v0.5.1](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/releases/tag/v0.5.1) released.
If you're using bower, just run `bower update`.

Comment: Solution suggested by urban_raccoons below works, while the accepted answer does not, possibly due to updates in ui-select code...

Answer (score 16):

I believe what you would do is use the `repeat=` clause and get rid of the value property. An example is here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/htm8UNxVOlC076LVVezE?p=preview

Which I sort of copied from:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/blob/master/examples/demo-bind-to-single-property.html

```
<ui-select ng-model="myObject.stateCode" id="stateCode">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select a state...">{{$select.selected.codeDescription}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="item.codeId as item in constants.states | filter: $select.search">
        <div ng-bind-html="item.codeDescription | highlight: $select.search"></div>
        <small ng-bind-html="item.codeId | highlight: $select.search"></small>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Comment: That works until you have a value bound to stateCode.  I think it is because of a binding between object vs value? The value does select the correct option in the dropdown, also when i have it locally(not in plunker) I get a parser error. http://plnkr.co/edit/uUDzrKFwT7Tl4fHGprC1

Comment: You're going to need to elaborate a little more about what exactly it is you want. Also - re: parser error, might be an issue w/ hosting it locally. Are you running it in a localhost web server or just opening the files with a browser?

Comment: This was fixed in a build from today.  https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/issues/130

Comment: it seems 'repeat' in 'ui-select-choices' binds the select value.but really, i dont know where should i found the doc

Comment: @Marks [there's an example here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/blob/master/examples/demo-bind-to-single-property.html). `ui-select` barely has documentation, you have to infer it from the examples.